# What can I scrape off the Visual Studio 2015 installation package (like SQL) and still leave it functional?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, minimum

What can I uninstall from [this large chunk of programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZL4r.png) without breaking Visual Studio Community 2015. I do not use any SQL services or any .NET frameworks for any sort of development, so I don't need SQL or .NET features. Unfortunately VS forced them upon me.
In fact, I only really use Visual Studio to code C/C++ and Fortran, and have no use for its other features.

In search for a solution I came across [this cool preview build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes) which would almost exactly be the solution to my predicament, but I need Intel C/C++/Fortran compiler and Intel Visual Fortran (extension for VS) compatibility to be maintained. Intel does not support non-official releases so VS Preview won't do.

Comment: does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: The issue is solved, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the VS 2015 through the default installation or custom default? If you chose the default installation, those installed items in your first screenshot should be required for the VS 2015, it is better to keep it to make the VS work stable.

If you chose the custom installation, please have a look at [the article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx) and it lists the custom components, then you can remove them if you do not need it anymore. To remove them, you can right click the VS 2015 item under Uninstall a program list table and choose Change-Modify, then uncheck the checkbox of those components that you selected in your original custom installation, then the VS installer will auto uninstall those components. Before you try to uninstall any components, I recommend you backup your Windows OS firstly, you can find the backup method per your OS edition search [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/products/windows?os=windows-10).

The .NET Framework is required and the basic component for VS, when you try to create any project types in VS, there is a default .NET Framework version like the following:

[image]